# Make Header fit Width of Screen

Tags: html, css

Right now, my header looks good on the screen, but it scrolls over like the header is too wide, if that makes sense? I have my width set to 100%, so is there something I'm missing?
This is the code.
HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<center>
<table border="0" width="950px">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="mainRunner"><img class="background" height="200px" src="http://i.imgur.com/1laWPRb.png" width="3000px" /> <img class="mainheader" height="150" src="http://i.imgur.com/sdqMfWT.png" width="500" /></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="contactinfo"><img class="phone" height="40" src="http://i.imgur.com/5Wew8PC.png" width="250" /> <a href="mailto:kerralt@aol.com"><img class="email" height="30" src="http://i.imgur.com/bXs6aht.png" width="200" /> </a></div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#header {
width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
height: 172px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -10px;
background-color: #ffffff;}

.mainheader
{
border: 0px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
top: -185px;
left: 265px;
}
.phone
{ 
position: relative;
top: -85px;
left: -2230px}
.email
{ 
position: relative;
top: -75px;
left: -2195px}
```

The website is http://kerryaltmantest.info

Thank you!

Comment: Just by looking at your code, I think a few problems are gonna be (1) your header image width is 3000px (2) `.email` and `.phone` have  `left:-2230px` and `left:-2195px`. Not sure how to fix your problem - if you provided a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) it would be easier - but I think you need to rethink a lot of these huge px values...

Comment: yep to  mutch relative rules to mainRunner http://jsfiddle.net/SG7Sb/1/

Comment: Thank you for that, I appreciate it. I do logically know that the width is the problem. But if I make that image smaller, when on higher screen resolutions, the header won't reach the left side of the screen. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `div` as;

```
<div class="mainRunner">
    <img class="background" height="200px" src="http://i.imgur.com/1laWPRb.png" width="3000px">
    <img class="mainheader" height="150" src="http://i.imgur.com/sdqMfWT.png" width="500">
</div>
```

It's width is `3000px` because of the first image's width `width="3000px`. Try to fix it. The first image is:

```
<img class="background" height="200px" src="http://i.imgur.com/1laWPRb.png" width="3000px">
```

Check `width="3000px"` in this image.

Comment: I know logically that's the problem. But if I make that image smaller, when on higher screen resolutions, the header won't reach the left side of the screen. Does that make sense?

Comment: No it doesn't make sense, you can set width of `header` to `100%`. It's not possible to figure out your `css/style` problem but I think you didn't implement that properly, still using `table` in layout!

Answer (score 0):

use background color image as background-image for table with repeat instead of img and also set the table width to 100%.

```
table
{
 background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/1laWPRb.png");
 background-repeat: repeat;
 width:100%;
}
```